# Powershell Resolve-DnsName not working when Private Endpoint enabled

Tags: azure, powershell, dns, endpoint

I have an Azure storage account with public IP address and can resolve this name using both nslookup and Resolve-DnsName. Output below, truncated for brevity.

C:>nslookup stgweb.blob.core.windows.net
Name:    blob.syd25prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net
Address:  20.60.72.36
Aliases:  stgweb.blob.core.windows.net

Resolve-DnsName -Name stgweb.blob.core.windows.net
Name       : blob.syd25prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net
QueryType  : A
TTL        : 60
Section    : Answer
IP4Address : 20.60.72.36

When I create a private endpoint the private IP address resolves correctly from an Azure VM in both nslookup and Resolve-DnsName. But I can no longer resolve the public name from outside of Azure using Resolve-DnsName, but can using NSlookup.

C:>nslookup stgweb.blob.core.windows.net
Name:    blob.syd25prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net
Address:  20.60.72.36
Aliases:  stgweb.blob.core.windows.net
stgweb.privatelink.blob.core.windows.net

PS>Resolve-DnsName -Name stgweb.blob.core.windows.net
Resolve-DnsName: stgweb.blob.core.windows.net : DNS name does not exist.

But Resolve-DnsName will resolve the blob.syd25prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net name
PS>Resolve-DnsName -Name blob.syd25prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net
blob.syd25prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net     A      60    Answer     20.60.72.36

Why is this, is there a way to get Resolve-DnsName to work correctly like NSlookup? Its not just storage accounts its anything with a private endpoint that fails.

Comment: Looks like the two commands are using different default name servers. Try specifying the name server in the request.

Answer (score 0):

•   When you **enable the private endpoint for a storage account, a private DNS zone is created with the name of ‘privatelink.blob.core.windows.net’ in which an ‘A’ host record is created for the storage account with a private IP address assigned** as shown below: -

[image: Private link DNS zone]

This is created along with a **private NIC configuration as below wherein it is implied or deployed that the private DNS integration for the NIC created is associated with the storage account as well as with the private link created for it due to which when you are trying to resolve the FQDN of the storage account, i.e., ‘kartikbstor.blob.core.windows.net’, it will not be accessible since it is privately associated with the IP address in the virtual network associated**. Therefore, only when you try to **‘nslookup’** for the **‘CNAME’** record created by you, i.e., *`‘blob.syd25prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net’ after creating private endpoint, it is not accessible since the private link DNS configuration takes into effect after private endpoint creation`*.

•   *`As the ‘nslookup’ from inside the Azure VM searches for the DNS entries in the respective virtual network’s private DNS zone only due to which the DNS ‘A’ record related to the private link are relayed back and the DNS resolution regarding it takes place. Similarly, when you hit the ‘Resolve-DNS’ command after creation of the private endpoint, this command tries to search for the ‘CNAME’ record, i.e., ‘blob.syd25prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net’ in the private DNS zone which is found but the public DNS name is not accessible any longer since its FQDN is no longer available in the private DNS zone created due to private link creation`*.

[image: Private DNS configuration]
[image: Networking endpoint]

Therefore, when you **create the private endpoint for a storage account, the public DNS entries are not accessible from inside the virtual network’s resources, i.e., Azure VM and instead are accessible from the public internet***.

For more detailed information, kindly refer to the below link: -

***https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=windowsserver2022-ps***

Comment: I know all the above but the problem is nslookup and resolve-dnsname are returning different results from the same vm using the same dns server. Nslookup works, resolve-dnsname does not.

Comment: Nslookup tries to resolve the hostname with the IP address on the assigned name server itself due to which while doing 'nslookup', the DNS resolution request is resolved through the private DNS zone itself but when you are doing 'resolve-dnsname' through the Azure VM, it is searching for the resolution in the DNS servers publicly that is, it forwarding the request to the public DNS on the internet and due to which it doesn't lookup for it in the private link configured DNS zone created. Hence, the 'resolve-dnsname' fails but nslookup doesn't

Comment: Here's the very specific commands I am using.  They all refer to external DNS (not Azure DNS), they're all run from my personal laptop not the VM in azure.  I have specifically set the DNS server (my ISP DNS) to prove that nslookup works (resolved to Public IP as expected since I am not using the Azure VM), resolve-dnsname does not.

Comment: PS C:\> nslookup stgweb.blob.core.windows.net 203.12.160.36  
Server:  dns2.tpgi.com.au  
Address:  203.12.160.36  

Non-authoritative answer:  
Name:    blob.syd25prdstr01a.store.core.windows.net  
**Address:  20.60.72.36**  
Aliases:  stgweb.blob.core.windows.net  
          stgweb.privatelink.blob.core.windows.net  

PS C:\> resolve-dnsname stgweb.blob.core.windows.net -server 203.12.160.36  
Resolve-DnsName: stgweb.blob.core.windows.net : **DNS name does not exist.**